# No run configurations for android project with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I had pushed by mistake `.iml` files on git (now removed from the repo) and when I pulled my project and imported it on `Android Studio 1.3` from `Gradle` configuration, even when refreshing the project with gradle I have the error `AndroidManifest.xml file not found`.

I tried to remove cache and restart, I deleted generated files and `.iml` files but I don't have any run configurations available, and the `Android` tab is empty.

How can I restore my project to a working state ?

**EDIT**

After following Y2K instructions I had to add :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

To the top of `app/app.gradle`and then everything was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy/Git clone what you have to a New Folder . Remove generated .idea folder and .iml s but keep gradle related files: settings.gradle,.gradle ,gradle folder & copy local.properties from any other project if you don't have them etc.

Now Import them , click the build.gradle file that you want to import . Your project will be imported

Comment: When I import the project by selecting the `build.gradle` from root folder it doesn't work and when I import the project by selecting `build.gradle` in the `app` folder the gradle sync displays `Error:(1,0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.`

Comment: It is the build.gradle from the root folder that you should run.  Also try removing gradle folder in your root folder and use a(copy) gradle folder from other working project or New project.

Comment: If you can go to settings ,->Build-> Gradle  Use Local Gradle and point to Android Studio Gradle . C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4

Comment: thank you I think android studio wasn't compatible with gradle 2.4

Comment: Yes there are some issues regarding compatibility with Android Build tools and Gradle.